# How to get password hash to create a principal from query?

Tags: sql-server, freetds

I use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) query to create server login.
I want to pass password like hash:

```
PASSWORD = hashed_password HASHED
```

How can I get the hash?

I use freetds to connect to server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking about existing logins, you can use the Microsoft's sp SP_HELP_REVLOGIN.
Here you can find the script to create this sp:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I want to create a new login by query.

Comment: @kaa: you need to know in advance the hash that the hashing algorithm will assign to your clear password?

Comment: But, you know, your suggestion is a part of the right answer. Here is a tutorial how to solve such problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f15a1ee1-e1df-4b51-987d-c1b094f2e71e/request-actual-example-of-create-login-with-password-hashed?forum=sqlsecurity